# How to use hex color codes in zsh/Screen?

Tags: zsh, gnu-screen

On a Raspberry Pi using zsh, I have set `PS1=%B%F{#50F862}%n@%m%f%b:%B%F{#625EF6}%~ %#%f%b` to mimic the default bash coloring of `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\]`, since I prefer to use `zsh`. This works as-expected when in a usual `ssh` session, but when I start a `screen` session,the prompt colors are grey.

If I change instead to `PS1=%B%F{green}%n@%m%f%b:%B%F{blue}%~ %#%f%b`, then the colors show up as expected (and, I must admit, look pretty indistinguishable - so this isn't a big problem, it's just a curiosity). How do I use hex color codes in a zsh prompt in screen?

Comment: My feeling is that _screen_ gets in your way. All in all, the colouring is made by the terminal application, based on the escape codes in the output, but there are layers in between which filter this output. _screen_ is such a layer, and perhaps it can't deal with the output produced by zsh when you try to use hex codes.

Comment: `%F{#50f862}` tells `zsh` to generate a terminal-specific sequence of bytes to instruct the terminal to display a certain color. If `zsh` doesn't have accurate information (via the `TERM` variable) about what terminal is being used, it can't generate the desired byte sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
zmodload zsh/nearcolor
```

Not all devices and programs support the hex-triplet colors; it looks like `screen` may be in the set that can only handle [256 colors](https://www.ditig.com/256-colors-cheat-sheet), and therefore it doesn't understand the escape codes it's getting. With the `nearcolor` module, `zsh` will attempt to map the hex color to one of the supported colors.

You can also specify the xterm color directly with `%F` and `%K`, and avoid loading any modules:

```
PROMPT='%B%F{93}%n@%m%f%b%F{240}:%f%B%K{112}%~ %#%k%b '
```

Comment: Well, that's disappointing that `screen` can only handle 256 colors - but, thank you for the tip on nearest approximation!